# Can i fix the fuction type "RETURNS SETOF"?

Tags: postgresql, greenplum, dbeaver

thank you for reading.

I use DBeaver tool for modifying functions made by pqsql.

But, when i modify the function.
Always, i need to set up the source of the return type.

For example,
i have a schema "test", then this is the create sql.
there is a data type "type_getdata" and, the function name is "getdata"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.getdata(p_userid "varchar")
    RETURNS SETOF test.type_getdata
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    VOLATILE
AS $$
```

then when i want to change the function.
i choose the button "View Function".
then, the data type is missing. like as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.getdata(p_userid "varchar")
    RETURNS SETOF type_getdata
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    VOLATILE
AS $$
```

So, if i have some change, i need to modify "type_getdata" to "test.type_getdata"
is there any ways to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't fix this in the UI of a client tool to begin with. You should change the SQL script that's stored in your git (or subversion) repository and then apply the new script to your database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Thank you for your reply. Can you explain more about it? i don't use git (or subversion), jusst use dbeaver and pgadmin. then, i can't do it?

Answer (score 0):

That is not a problem, it is Postgres design.  And it has nothing with returning setof. 
When you login you get a default SEARCH PATH. The setting determines the available schemas and the order they are searched when database objects are referenced and NOT fully qualified. What is happening is the schema TEST is not in your search path, and you are being forced (by Postgtes not DBeaver) to specify the fully qualified. To see your current search path run

```
show search_path;
```

You can change this at the session level by changing with set command, assuming your current path is *"$user",public* you may want something like

```
set search_path="$user",public,test;
```

That last only for the current session, see your DBA for a permanent change. But be careful, if anyone later creates type_getdata in PUBLIC (or any other database object with corresponding name as in test) then you will use/change that one not the one in TEST.  
In a multiple schema environment you are much better off using a fully qualified names. I.E. test.getdata(...) As you are also doing with your function name.

Comment: "*you are much better off using a fully qualified name*" - it seems the OP knows that, but cannot get the dbeaver "View Function" feature to display them